# How to handle ReactJS state when using a shared component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have the following scenario, two forms (posts and notes) and one component for comments entry. 
The comments form component is reused.

As when combining two reducers I have state split into two parts (posts and notes), subsequently I have posts.errors and notes.error objects, which stores error information, specific to posts and notes respectively.

Now, as I am reusing the comments form, the form should alert when an error occurs, if error comes from posts it should alert with specific to posts message, in case if the origin is notes, then it should return specific to notes error message, how this could be achieved?

Let me add some additional info.

Posts reducer's state shape is as follows:

```
{error:{}, comments:[], posts:[]}
```

Accordingly, notes has:

```
{error:{}, comments:[], notes:[]}
```

Comments form edits a single item (passed from parent to child) item and calls an update action to update the comment in the database. When an error occurs, the above scenario should fire.

Comment: It will be good if some code snippets are provided.

Comment: I agree, but the code is big, the question is more on  if the approach is correct.

Comment: It's hard to tell what is your actual problem without code sample. Please try to be more specific what have you tried so far and what problem you have with this implementation.